# How can I define a Rust function type which returns its own type?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm learning Rust, and still very much trying to get my head around it.  Consider the following Go definition:

```go
type FnType func(paramType) FnType
```

It's just a function that returns a function of the same type.  Can something similar be implemented in Rust?  And, ideally, can it be done generically, so that `paramType` is specified by the client?

Comment: In Rust, you might want to read about *session types* to implement compile-time checked FSMs. Otherwise, an `enum` with a method consuming `self` (and an event) and returning `Self` (or `Result<Self>`) is more flexible (but transitions are not compile-time checked).

Comment: If any of you fine gents/ladies want to answer my new (related) question, it's over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130789/in-rust-what-is-the-most-idiomatic-way-to-implement-a-simple-fsm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some digging in the docs and took to the playground and I think I've been able to answer this myself, although it does require an intermediary type: an `enum`, to be specific.

```
fn main() {
    let mut state = State::Some(first);
    while let State::Some(s) = state {
        state = s(0)
    }
}

enum State<T> {
    Some(fn(T) -> State<T>),
    None,
}

fn first(_: i32) -> State<i32> {
    println!("First");
    State::Some(second)
}

fn second(_: i32) -> State<i32> {
    println!("Second");
    State::None
}
```

You can verify that it runs on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=20d752b48fe8ab2d9d66d4da8d89aae7&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Answer (score 3):

Cyclic types are unsupported in Rust:

```
type a = fn(String) -> a;
```

Yields the following error:

```
error: unsupported cyclic reference between types/traits detected [--explain E0391]
 --> <anon>:1:24
  |>
1 |> type a = fn(String) -> a;
  |>                        ^
note: the cycle begins when processing `a`...
note: ...which then again requires processing `a`, completing the cycle.
```

See on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=type%20a%20%3D%20fn(String)%20-%3E%20a%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: On the other hand... I wonder if there's a trick with `Self`?

Comment: I edited the question to add some context.  Maybe there's an alternative solution...

Comment: @burfl: There are alternatives, but as they completely change the question from "how to define a recursive fn" to "how to best implement FSMs"... let's keep to the first question (the second might be off-topic, maybe...)

Comment: That's fair.  I'll undo the edit and perhaps make a new question.