# In Rust, what is the most idiomatic way to implement a simple FSM?

Tags: generics, rust

In learning Rust, I'm trying to implement a simple, clean FSM, very similar to [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/GrthJHzN7n) which I've used many times in Go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type StateFn func(interface{}) StateFn

func First(interface{}) StateFn {
    fmt.Println("First")
    return Second
}

func Second(interface{}) StateFn {
    fmt.Println("Second")
    return nil
}

func main() {
    for state := First(nil); state != nil; state = state(nil) {}
}
```

I'm hoping for something similarly clean and expressive and, ideally, generic, so that I don't have to use the Rust equivalent of `interface{}` in the func parameter.

This question is an extension of [How can I define a Rust function type which returns its own type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130293/in-rust-how-can-i-define-a-function-type-which-returns-its-own-type?noredirect=1#comment65606785_39130293).

Comment: While this may not be an exact duplicate of the existing question, your question was in danger of being closed for other reasons. I figured pointing to that one was at least marginally more useful.

Comment: In the interest of not repeating the same mistake, would you mind sharing the "other reasons"?  No hard feelings, of course.  It's for my benefit :)

Comment: I actually forget which specific ones, but I think there were a few for *too broad*, maybe some on *opinion based*. [See some detail on these](/help/closed-questions). In general, asking how to solve a problem without showing some self effort towards it wont get the best response. Not including code inline is another faux pas.

Comment: This is actually translatable almost line-for-line.  I can't answer the question now that it's closed, but here's the solution: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=20d752b48fe8ab2d9d66d4da8d89aae7&version=stable&backtrace=0